# Terminating TFTPD after file transfer

Tags: linux, bash, tftp, inetd

I am using `inetutils` `tftpd` which is started via `inetd` using the following entry in `inetd.conf`:

```
tftp       dgram   udp     wait    root   /bin/tftpd -p -u root -s /home
```

(ignore the use of root account and /home directory, it's just for testing purposes, it will be changed later).

`inetd` version is `inetd (GNU inetutils) 1.7`

`tftpd` version is `tftp-hpa 5.2, with remap, with tcpwrappers`

Everything works fine, but the problem is that I don't have any information about the file transfer status. Having in mind that I have more than 10 scripts that rely on `tftpd`, I need to either:

- terminate `tftpd` after the file transfer or error (because it keeps running in the background doing nothing)
- make it display file transfer status in a way that I can `grep` `sed` or at least `$?`

Is this possible, and if not, what other `tftpd` server should I use?

Comment: Hello Ulrik. Unless you intend to write your own TFTP server, this question is probably more suited for serverfault.com or superuser.com - "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming".

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that, but I am using `TFTP` as integral part of my scripting engine, so I thought I could get some useful input from this community...

Comment: TFTP is as dumb as a protocol can be, and tftpd is scary from the security point of view. Take a look at https://wiki.python.org/moin/tftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the man page for tftpd:

> --timeout timeout, -t timeout
>
> When run from inetd this specifies how long, in seconds, to wait for a second connection before terminating the server. inetd will then respawn the server when another request comes in. The default is 900 (15 minutes.)

Try changing your inetd.conf like so:

```
tftp       dgram   udp     wait    root   /bin/tftpd -t 5 -p -u root -s /home
```

Then restart inetd and test.

Comment: Your answer was the key - I wrote a `bash` script that looks for `tftpd` in the process list and reports the status. btw, `GNU tftpd` is picky about the order of given arguments, they need to be specified in the order listed in the man page...